# Getting mother’s birth certificate from lwow Rosa 1945?

Tags: birth-records, russia, 1940s

My mother was born in 1945 in lwow Rosja.

How I can get her birth certificate?

Comment: I had to cut-and-paste into a text editor to figure out that the placename being asked about begins with a lowercase L, not an uppercase i. I wonder if it's supposed to be "Lvov, Russia" (i.e. the city that's actually in Ukraine)?

Comment: Please do not include the name of your mother because she was born less than 100 years ago unless it passes our privacy policy at [help/on-topic]. Did you get her birth location as “lwow Rosja” by word of mouth or from a document?

Comment: Another possibility: Lwów In Poland. We really need to understand the source of the placename with a document image if at all possible.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the place is Lwów (Polish name) or Lviv (current transliteration from Cyrillic) - it's a city currently in Ukraine, in 1939 it was annexed by the USSR, previously part of Poland. To get her birth certificate, you need to go to ZAGS (civil registry) archive in Lviv. I don't think they do it remotely, but things change, yo can check that. If not, you probably can find and hire a local representative for that, it shouldn't be too expensive.